# ios 7.1 - UIDatePicker will bring View appear lag

Tags: performance, uidatepicker, ios7.1

Here it is. I created an `UITableView` in current controller, and it's static cell type. When I touched the button, will push this controller to UINavigationController, I found that it will take 3s delay to open, that's slow, sometimes we will think that we didn't touch the button correctly, kind bad UX.

So I tried Time Profile Tool and saw it invoke Calendar library, I tried to remove these two `UIDatePicker` from `UITableView`, and try it again, yes it's quick as its used to be around 1s.

So the question is how to remove this delay while it's still loading `UIDatePicker` in it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading that many UIDatePickers via Storyboard is sure to slow down your navigation.

- Create your UIDatepicker(s) programmatically
- If you need to pass data from the picker as the view appears create in viewWillAppear
- If you don't need any data from them until the view has been loaded create in viewDidAppear

My application required data on display so I created mine in viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

1. Remove UIDatePicker from UITableView
2. Created UIDatePicker programmatically in viewDidAppear

Then its energy back.